# Scheduler node always above 100% utilization

Tags: airflow-scheduler, google-cloud-composer

We're running Cloud Composer on a 5 node, n1-standard-2 cluster running composer-1.11.3-airflow-1.10.9. Private IP is enabled. Python 3 is selected. We currently have around 30 DAGs, some containing over 100 tasks. Most DAGs run once a day.

The node running the `airflow scheduler` workload is consistently running at around 150% CPU utilisation regardless of the number of running tasks. The only way to lower the CPU usage is to remove DAGs until only 5 or 6 remain (obviously not an option). What we've tried:

- We have followed this [Medium article](https://medium.com/swlh/the-smarter-way-of-scaling-with-composers-airflow-scheduler-on-gke-88619238c77b) detailing how to run the scheduler service on a dedicated node however we cannot find a configuration that reduces the CPU usage. We've tried a node as powerful as an e2-highcpu-32 running on a 100 GB SSD. Usage remained at 150%.
- We've tried to update the `airflow.cfg` variables to reduce the frequency the `dags` directory is parsed via settings such as `store_serialized_dags` and `max_threads`. Again, this did not have any impact on the CPU usage.

For reference the other nodes all run at 30-70% CPU for the majority of the time, spiking to over 100% for short periods when big DAGs are running. No node has any issue with memory usage, with between 2 GB and 4 GB used.

We plan on adding more DAGs in future and are concerned the scheduler may become a bottle neck with this current setup. Are there any other configuration options available to reduce the CPU usage to allow for a future increase in DAG number?

Edit in response to Ines' answer:
I'm seeing the CPU usage as a percentage in the `Monitoring` tab, the node running the scheduler service is coloured orange:
[image]
Additionally, when I look at the pod running `airflow scheduler` this is the CPU usage, pretty much always 100%:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please, have a look for the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/monitoring-dashboard#environment), which describes `CPU usage per node` metric. Can you elaborate where do you see the percentage values, since the documentation mentioned a core time usage ratio:

> A chart showing the usage of CPU cores aggregated over all running
> Pods in the node, measured as a core time usage ratio. This does not
> include CPU usage of the App Engine instance used for the Airflow UI
> or Cloud SQL instance. High CPU usage is often the root cause of
> Worker Pod evictions. If you see very high usage, consider scaling out
> your Composer environment or changing the schedule of your DAG runs.

In the meantime, there is an ongoing workaround and it would be worth trying. You should follow these steps to limit CPU usage on syncing POD:

1. Go to `environment configuration` page and click `view cluster workloads`
2. Click `airflow-scheduler`, then edit
3. Find name: `gcs-syncd` and add:

```
resources:
  limits:
    cpu: some value (you can try with 300m)
  requests:
    cpu: 10m
```

then click `save` (at the bottom).

4. Repeat the procedure for airflow-worker.
5. We have to edit also the section of airflow-scheduler of the workload `airflow-scheduler`. Click on edit the YAML file and for the section `airflow-scheduler` add:

```
resources:
  limits:
    cpu: 750m
  requests:
    cpu: 300m
```

It would be great if you could try the aforementioned steps and see if it improves the performance.

Sometimes bucket's `/logs` might consist of lot of files that causes `gcs-syncd` to use CPU much while doing an internal synchronization of the logs. You can try to remove some of the oldest logs of the bucket `gs://<composer-env-name>/logs`. As an example, if you would like to remove all logs of May, please use the following command:

```
gsutil -m rm -r gs://europe-west1-td2-composter-a438b8eb-bucket/logs/*/*/2020-05*
```

Ideally, the GCE instances shouldn't be running over 70% CPU at all times, or the Composer environment may become unstable during resource usage.

Comment: Thanks @ines, I've edited my question to provide more info, I'll try to follow your recommended steps.

Comment: Yes, I've implemented the steps you've suggested. If I understand them correctly these steps allocate less resources to the GCS sync and more resources to the scheduler. This has resulted in a minor decrease in CPU usage (per the `Monitoring` tab) to ~120%. I'm not sure this directly answers the question I asked, I'd much prefer the CPU usage to be <90% by editing the dagbag parsing schedule rather than restricting resources. Having a node running at over 100% was never an issue with previous Composer versions so I still feel something buggy is happening here.