# Why does Google Cloud Composer use 100% of scheduler's CPU?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

as the the title states - in Google Cloud Composer, version 1.20.4 (Airflow version 2.4.3), the **Total schedulers CPU usage** metric constantly oscillates around 110%. There are no DAGs running throughout that period (aside from the standard health check DAG of course).

Is that normal behavior you've observed?

Is this just how much vCPU Airflow scheduler needs to function?

Can this number somehow be brought down?

If so, is it worth bringing it down from cost perspective, or it does not matter?

Comment: Does this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63666222/scheduler-node-always-above-100-utilization/63669667#63669667) help you?

Comment: Hi @BloodthirstyPlatypus, Did the above link help you in resolving the issue?